# Add Rounded Corners to SurfaceTexture

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, vuforia

I'm streaming a video using VideoPlayback example provided by [Vuforia Augmented Reality SDK](https://developer.vuforia.com/) which uses a SurfaceTexture to display frames. Currently the video is displayed in a rectangular window. What I want to do is to make the corners of frames round. I've been looking for a solution to this for a couple of days now but I'm not sure as to how I should approach this problem. Should I convert the SurfaceTexture into something else (e.g. Bitmap), edit it and then convert it back? Should I somehow combine the texture with something else? ( I read somewhere that you can use something like a transparency mask but couldn't find much more than that). Or should I edit the shader?

I'd really appreciate it if you put me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a eglsurface as the consumer of mediaplayer, process the texture of every frame to round corners then draw it to the surfaceview of your UI layout.